# DESede Decrypt Issue

Tags: java, encryption, des

I am trying to understand some legacy code where one of the parameter to `Cipher.init` is 2. What does 2 signify here?

```
try
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes));
    }

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(2, key);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does 2 signify here?

That's `opmode`. From [`Cipher` class Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html):

```
void init(int opmode, Key key)
```

I believe 2 is `DECRYPT_MODE`. See the [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I went through the documentation. There are several modes, how can I know, which digit stands for which mode like 2 for ENCRYPT_MODE, 1 for DECRYPT_MODE etc

Comment: @John - I think they are an enumeration, and *not* a bit mask value.